# "Field 'posts' is missing required arguments: id",

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphql

I am trying to play around with rails hooked up to graphql and I have the following error trying to display a series of posts by a user

> "Field 'posts' is missing required arguments: id"

Here is my query:

```
query {
 posts(user_id: 10, type: "Video") {
    title
    file
  }
}
```

And in my query_type.rb file I have the following defined:

```
    field :posts, [Types::PostType], null: false do
      argument :id, ID, required: true, as: :user_id
      argument :type, String, required: true
    end

    def posts(user_id:, type:)
      posts = Post.where("user_id = ? AND type = ?", user_id, type)
    end
```

It is a simple query. I'm new to this technology (GraphQL) and I don't see what the problem is. Can someone pinpoint what is wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send the exact name in the parameters when running the query.

In your schema definition you have 2 required arguments called `id` of type `ID` and `type` of type `string`. So you have 2 options:

Update your query to send in the correct name `id`:

```
query {
 posts(id: "10", type: "Video") {
    title
    file
  }
}
```

Or, update your schema definition to receive a `user_id`:

```
field :posts, [Types::PostType], null: false do
  argument :user_id, ID, required: true, as: :user_id
  argument :type, String, required: true
end

def posts(user_id:, type:)
  posts = Post.where("user_id = ? AND type = ?", user_id, type)
end
```